# How to install Google Play app in Android Studio emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I am completely new to using Android Studio and I am trying to install the Google Play app on the emulator. I have installed the `Google Repository` and `Google Play Services` as well as a `Google APIs x86 Atom System Image` from the SDK manager and I am able to set up Google Play Services for my sample application.

I would now like to install the Google Play application on my emulator. How can this be done ? Any suggestions or a solution itself would be most appreciated. Also, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: google play? you mean playstore?

Comment: This worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291902/android-studio-emulator-does-not-come-with-play-store-for-api-23

Answer (score 144):

Starting with Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1, you have now some options of devices that come with the Play Store app built-in (like Nexus 5X and Nexus 5 on image below).

[image]

**Also,** you should use a system-image which targets "Google Play" (instead of Google APIs),
as said images come with "Google Play" pre-installed, and you can just like a real device open "Google play" and update it.

**Update 2022;** but even with above, you cannot use the Emulator to test Google Play Billing:

> - You must install your application on a real device to test Google Play Billing,
> - Or, ask Google for "closed testing" permission.
>
> see [How to test In-app Billing on an emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26100032/8740349)

Comment: Great! And what if I want to test my app on a emulator with Play Store, but in **Tablet mode**?

Comment: I've been searching for a few hours and finally ran across this! Thank you!

Comment: I don't see this option.  Are you sure it is there?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I checked today and it is still there, need to scroll down a bit

Answer (score 96):

After a long while of testing, everything seems to be outdated. I can't find necessary APK's like `GoogleLoginService.apk`, etc.

I got it to work by installing two virtual devices.

1. My Device (a Samsung Galaxy Tab A with custom skin and sizes)
2. A device, which had the "Play Store Available" icon in your AVD-Manager on the site where you can create a new profile.

I installed the first device and the second device with the same Android version, and used one profile from Samsung (because my tablet is a Samsung).

After that step, I compared the `config.ini` file located in:

```
C:\Users\USER\.android\avd\DEVICE_ID
```

On Ubuntu/Linux it'll be in

```sh
~/.android/avd/DEVICE_ID
```

Change the following variables to:

```
PlayStore.enabled = true
image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-27\google_apis_playstore\x86\
tag.display=Google Play
tag.id=google_apis_playstore
```

Here's an example diff of what fields will be changed:

[image: Screenshot: AVD Device config.ini differeneces]

After that you'll probably have to re-download the system image for the device, which you can do from *Tools > AVD Manager*.

Here's an example screenshot of what that'd look like:

[image: Screenshot: Installing system image in AVD Manager]

Once done, restart the device, and Play store will be installed and ready to use.

Comment: Please be careful with your formatting, and be sure to preview your answer before posting. Your entire answer was indented by four spaces which made it appear as a code block, and made it difficult to read. I've reformatted it for you; please review to make sure everything is correct, but also to evaluate how the formatting was achieved for future posts.

Comment: You may also have to download the system image for the device again if the API version is different or the image doesn't already exist. I had to re-download the system image when i was moving from API 29 on Google Pixel 3a to API 30 on Google Pixel 3 XL. If the system image is missing, you'll get `PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` when you try to run the emulator. You can download system image from _Tools > AVD Manager_

Comment: Working in 2021! Thank you!

Comment: When I touch on download I get this error "All packages are not available for download !, The following packages are not available:
  - Package id system-images; android-23; google_apis_playstore; x86 "

Comment: The best solution until 2021!

Comment: Heroic.  I have a working emulator for API 30 finally

Comment: The real question is why isn't AVD showing emulator images with Google Play???

Comment: you are smart one!!

Comment: Pixel C API 31 works fine now after changing ini

Comment: this solution not working on sdk level 22 in android studio emulator using nexus s

Comment: It looks like it is working only for those versions, which have google play enabled versions in the list, 9 and higher.

Comment: Tested on API 33 (Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1) - works like a charm.

Comment: 2023 update - following the direction from @IgorGanapolsky from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72566489/1701589 and then updating the config.ini file as described above worked like a charm for API 31!

Comment: Why is the most crowbar-like solution is always the most reliable and time-resistant?! API 33 AS 4.1.2 MacOS 14+ works!

Answer (score 5):

Start by installing the Play Store package in SDK Manager. You can follow the steps on [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dl-AXszyIwk&t=1s)

After that step, edit the `config.ini` file located in:

```
C:\Users\USER\.android\avd\DEVICE_ID
```

Or you can also click on `Show on Disk` in the device options.

Change the following variables to:

```
PlayStore.enabled = true
image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-27\google_apis_playstore\x86\
tag.display=Google Play
tag.id=google_apis_playstore
```

Once done, restart the device, and Play store will be installed and ready to use.

Answer (score 3):

Download Google apps (GoogleLoginService.apk , GoogleServicesFramework.apk , Phonesky.apk)
from http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/Google_Apps#Universal_Packages_2

Start your emulator:

```
emulator -avd VM_NAME_HERE -partition-size 500 -no-audio -no-boot-anim
```

Then use the following commands:

## Remount in rw mode

```
adb shell mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system
```

## Allow writing to app directory on system partition

```
adb shell chmod 777 /system/app
```

## Install following apk

```
adb push GoogleLoginService.apk /system/app/.
adb push GoogleServicesFramework.apk /system/app/.
adb push Phonesky.apk /system/app/. # Vending.apk in older versions
adb shell rm /system/app/SdkSetup*
```

Refer: [to this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154222/google-play-on-android-4-0-emulator)

Comment: /system not in /proc/mounts

Comment: in the emulator, with whatever tools are the latest as of Feb, 2017, the emulator needs to be launched from the command line with:
`-writable-system`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42280124/3003905

Answer (score 2):

1. [Choose device that support play market](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erHIB.png)
2. [Choose your android version ( I I recommend the "R" version )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6YiI.png)
3. [Choose x86 image ( Target- GOOGLE PLAY, NOT Google APIs! )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxgae.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32956845)

Comment: Not available for Android versions earlier than 9

Answer (score 1):

On new version of sdk, you could browse:

```
C:\Users\{$User}\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools
```

Create `avd` from command line:

```
android create avd --name bphone --package "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86_64"
```

There will be a question asking you to custom profile, say `yes`, then an asking to install CH Play or not, just type `yes`.

Then, open AVD Manager inside Android Studio to reconfig.
Notes: Remember to change CPU/ABI to `x86`

Answer (score 0):

All this is not necessary on the latest MM API images.

All that was needed for me was to:

```
adb remount
adb push Phonesky.apk /system/priv-app/.
adb stop && adb restart
```

Comment: I do not think this is how to install Google Play Store.