# VS Emulator for Android: Google Play Store Crashes After Fresh Install of Gapps (Google Play Services)

Tags: android-emulator, visual-studio-2015, google-play-services, visual-studio-emulator

I've installed Gapps (Gapps CyanogenMod 13, Android 6.0 – Marshmallow (for Android 6.0 Gapps also) HDPI / MDPI / TINY: gapps-600-base-20151016-1-signed.zip) on my Android guest OS on VS Emulator for Android (using the 5.7" Marshmallow 6.0.0 XHDPI Phone API Level 23 device image) per https://stackoverflow.com/a/31564712/229011 (and got a success message in adb) and the only thing that is surfacing after restarting the emulator and guest OS is the Google Play Store.  Launching it just opens a blank white screen which promptly closes.

I've even tried drag-and-drop install of the gapps zip and it says it is successful and prompts to shutdown (which the adb method didn't do), but there is still no change.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and then I added my google account to the emulator and it worked..

```
Settings -> Accounts -> Add Account -> Google
```

After that I was able to open "Play Store" and update google related services like "Google +" so that they ran.... Now I have a google map I can use in my emulator :-)

I've done this with the API Level 21 emulator using the 5.0 Gapps package

Comment: You're perfectly right, it says that in Logcat as well:

`03-25 14:24:19.228 1161-1161/com.android.vending W/Finsky: [1] FinskyApp.getCurrentAccount: No account configured on this device.`

My problem with Marshmallow 6.0 image is that Add Account is missing Google type. It worked fine for me with older API images.

Comment: I'm using the LG Nexus 5X Visual Studio Android Emulator (API level 23) and it is missing the Google option in Add Account.

Comment: Hmmm yea that's unfortunate :-( why can't it all just stay working....  The closest I've been able to get with API 23 is in the gapps package if you unzip gapps and install the "PrebuiltGmsCore.apk" then that will give you the option for adding the Google account. But clicking it crashes play services. I also tried the openapps packages but those have the same issues.  I'm hoping after the marshmallow matures a bit that a new gapp package or VS image will resolve this. I'll check back in if I figure something out

Comment: Did you manage to get it working in the end?  I'm trying Marshmallow with the same results, no Google Account selection.

Comment: I haven't :-/ still just been sticking with the 4.4 emulators for google maps and testing on a physical device for 6.0. It's weird google makes it so those can't just be included by default. It's a real PITA :-p