# Android emulator with Marshmallow,Lollipop doesn't have GApps

Tags: android, android-emulator

So, I am using Android emulators after a while. I noticed that for Emulator with Marshmallow and Lollipop GApps aren't present when created in Android Studio ( I'm using 2.1.2) . Has this been default? If so, where and how can I get the GApps?

Edit: I saw this link [install gapps instruction](http://www.flinkd.org/2015/02/installing-google-play-on-the-android-emulator-api-21-lollipop/) from another stackoverflow link but not sure if this is the same.
  Appreciate the inputs.

Comment: You mean like Gmail, Maps, Chrome, etc? I don't remember them ever having it... You could sideload them if you really wanted it though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio emulator does not come with Play Store for API 23](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291902/android-studio-emulator-does-not-come-with-play-store-for-api-23)

Comment: @cricket_007 I mean google playstore, gmail et. al.

Comment: @b1izzard I saw that but I am having issue with Emulator of lollipop version as well.

Comment: Download the package you want from [OpenGapps](http://opengapps.org/)