# Google Play store icon not visible on emulator. android

Tags: android, android-studio

Can anyone tell me a simpler way of making google play store icon visible on emulator. I have tried multiple solutions but none have worked.

Comment: You want to use Play Store in emulator?

Comment: Which multiple solutions you are trying?

Comment: @pRaNaY http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-install-google-play-services-on-android-emulator-genymotion/

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options:

1. Install it on the default android emulator. You can see an answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34581874/4287861)
2. Use Genymotion (which is an awesome and free for **personal** use Emulator) and install google play store easily by following [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-install-google-services-on-genymotion/en) guide.

I personally use Genymotion in my projects and it works amazing and also provide you a lot of targets (e.g. Samsung, LG etc.).

Comment: Genymotion is not free, unless you use it for personal projects only. It is most definitely a huge improvement over the default emulator though.