# Android install google play to emulator - Read-only file system

Tags: android, android-emulator

Has searched solution to install google play to emulator but none of the solution work for me. Always got read-only file system and can't resolve it. Anyone has idea? I am using API 19

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb root

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb remount
remount succeeded

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb push C:\Temp\gapps-kk-20140105-signed\system\priv-app\GoogleServicesFramework.apk /system/priv-app/
adb: error: failed to copy 'C:\Temp\gapps-kk-20140105-signed\system\priv-app\GoogleServicesFramework.apk' to '/system/priv-app/GoogleServicesFramework.apk': Read-only file system

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb push C:\Temp\gapps-kk-20140105-signed\system\priv-app\GoogleLoginService.apk /system/priv-app/
adb: error: failed to copy 'C:\Temp\gapps-kk-20140105-signed\system\priv-app\GoogleLoginService.apk' to '/system/priv-app/GoogleLoginService.apk': Read-only file system

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb push C:\Temp\gapps-kk-20140105-signed\system\priv-app\Phonesky.apk /system/priv-app/
adb: error: failed to copy 'C:\Temp\gapps-kk-20140105-signed\system\priv-app\Phonesky.apk' to '/system/priv-app/Phonesky.apk': Read-only file system

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb push C:\Temp\gapps-kk-20140105-signed\system\priv-app\GmsCore.apk /system/priv-app/
adb: error: failed to copy 'C:\Temp\gapps-kk-20140105-signed\system\priv-app\GmsCore.apk' to '/system/priv-app/GmsCore.apk': Read-only file system

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb shell
root@generic_x86:/ # mount
rootfs / rootfs ro,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
/dev/block/vda /system ext4 ro,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/vdb /cache ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,errors=panic,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/vdc /data ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,errors=panic,data=ordered 0 0
root@generic_x86:/ # mount -o rw,remount /system
mount: Read-only file system
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291902/android-studio-emulator-does-not-come-with-play-store-for-api-23 You need gapps package and Genymotion ARM Translation zips and directly push to emulator. It will flash the archive and then reboot itself.

Comment: It is true the Emulator for API 23 didn't came with gapps. There are few places to download it which is what I did. Above solution for many people but not for me. I might not want to use genymotion if the android emulator works. Please provide details step.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio emulator does not come with Play Store for API 23](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291902/android-studio-emulator-does-not-come-with-play-store-for-api-23)