# Emulator causing this error Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I can successfully run my app on actual device, but when i try to run my app on emulator i got these error messages.

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the
>   boot class loader; no stack available
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;

I have tried these emulators

- Nexus 5X API 22
- Nexus 6 API 22

I am testing my app on these devices.

- Samsung s5
- Samsung s7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, You need to install Google Play Store in your emulator. Please have a look at here: [Android Studio emulator does not come with Play Store for API 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291902/android-studio-emulator-does-not-come-with-play-store-for-api-23)