# Installed google app in emulator automatically geting removed after restarting Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to install google play in AVD of Android studio. I followed second answer of [Android Studio emulator does not come with Play Store for API 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291902/android-studio-emulator-does-not-come-with-play-store-for-api-23)

Here what i tried already:

1.I have created the avd with x86 system image of android 7.1.1 with nexus 5.

2. I have downloaded gapp file open_gapps-x86-7.1-mini-20170209 from http://opengapps.org/  and extracted apks with lzip.
3. Then i start AVD from AVD manager manually then executed following commands:

adb root

adb remount

adb push PrebuiltGmsCore.apk /system/priv-app/

adb push GoogleServicesFramework.apk /system/priv-app/

adb push GoogleLoginService.apk /system/priv-app/

adb push Phonesky.apk /system/priv-app/

adb stop

adb start

4. Then I saw the play store app got installed successfully.

But when i close the avd and start again , i surprised to see that play store app disappeared. I tried it again and again, But unfortunately I got same results. I want to know why this happening and how to fix it. Thank you.