# How to install Gapps for Android 6.0 on Android Studio 2.3.3 Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I need to crete a new AVD with LG k10 specs and Android 6.0 on Android Studio (2.3.3) Emulator.

I followed this guide: [Installing Google Play Services on an Android Studio emulator](https://medium.com/@dai_shi/installing-google-play-services-on-an-android-studio-emulator-fffceb2c28a1)

After downloading and installing, when I run my Virtual Device now I can see the Play Store App.

But I have an issue: **I can't login with my google account**.

I receive the follow screen:

[image: google account login]

The login failed but I received on my Gmail account the alert about connection from a new device.

The login failed also creating a brand new account.

Internet connection on Virtual Device works, I can navigate on internet via default Browser.

**How to install correctly Gapps for Android 6.0 on Android Studio Emulator?**

Answer (score 0):

this link might help You, I have tryed installing many apps on emulator and I think it might just fit and help with Your problem.
Link:
http://www.flinkd.org/installing-google-play-on-the-android-emulator-api-21-lollipop/

And heres the full walktrough:
[Android Studio emulator does not come with Play Store for API 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291902/android-studio-emulator-does-not-come-with-play-store-for-api-23)