# Is there any android emulator that supports Playready DRM

Tags: android, android-emulator, playready

I'm creating an android application that will be able to play protected streams using exoplayer and I'd like to test it on an android emulator.

So far I haven't been able to find any solution that would allow me to test Playready protected streams.
Is there any android emulator or some king of plugin that can play it ?

Comment: You can install ExoPlayer from the [Play Store] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43489398/469983).

Comment: I can simply use bluestacks to install apps from play store. what Im asking about is PlayReady DRM , this technology is not supported by android emulators

Comment: I doubt there is any. They could in theory use SW playready with test certificate but that would not allow you playing any production content anyway (search for Security Level - SL150 vs SL2000 vs SL3000).