# Android Emulator without playstore on android studio 3.1 Latest release

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have updated my android studio **3.0.1** to **3.1** yesterday and i was trying to create AVD of **nexus 5 & nexus 5X** which default comes with playstore. I installed **x86** system image of naugat Android 7.0(**Google Apis**) on it. When download completes and i boot my AVD then it contains some google apps (gmail,playmusic,playmovie) but doesn't contain google play store or play services. Why it happens? In earlier version of android studio (e.g. 3.0.1) if i follow the same process then it creates AVD with playstore. Can anyone please tell me what's going wrong in this?

[[Image of nexus 5 & 5X with playstore logo][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgSPR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgSPR.png)

[[Image of my created AVDs not showing playstore symbols][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhDaL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhDaL.png)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a solution. I was selecting system image x86 android nougat 7.0(**Google Apis**) so, it was only including some google apps but it was not including google play store. I didn't receive any perfect reply on stackoverflow after posting my question so, i report a bug from android studio (**Help > Submit Feedback**) and they gave me the perfect answer. I was selecting system image having google Apis but if i want to get play store installed on emulator i have to select system images having (**google play**).

[image: see this image]

I know it's a silly mistake but no one have replied me with this answer so, i think i should have to post my answer so others can refer this and get help from it so, i have posted my answer.

Comment: This is not universal. For example in my Android studio, I dont see any downloadable image with Google Play. There is no such thing. All downloadable x86 images are labeled as "Api XY with Google APIs". And they all work fine, except Android 10 (API 29) which mysteriously doesnt containt Google Play app.

Answer (score 33):

You should create a new emulator. Before opening it for the first time, follow these 3 easy steps:

1. Go to `C:\Users\\[user]\.android\avd\\[your virtual device folder]` (Windows) or `/Users/[user]/.android/avd/[your virtual device folder]` (MacOS), open `config.ini` with a text editor
2. Change `PlayStore.enabled=false` to `PlayStore.enabled=true`
3. Change `image.sysdir.1 = system-images\android-[version]\google_apis\x86\` to
   `image.sysdir.1 = system-images\android-[version]\google_apis_playstore\x86\`

Comment: vow, super hacky way!

Comment: Excellent! Changing the config.ini changes the status of the AVD, and instead of Play icon it will provides a download link to system image that has Play Store in it. For some reason system images with play store is not listed in system images list. This is the only option that enables one to download system images with play store. Thanks for the information shared on changing the config.ini file.

Comment: Note: After changing the config.ini, refresh the avd list (refresh icon in the bottom right of avd manager) to make download link appear else it will show error on starting.

Comment: For mac, the path is ~/.android/avd

Comment: still works in 2021! just needs to relaunch Android Studio and click on download.

Comment: Worked like a breeze! How do you find out this info? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Nougat from "Recommended" tab, not from "x86 Images" tab.

Comment: Yes, your answer is also correct but i think it doesn't point what's the actual problem. i suggest you to read my own answer because I found what's the actual problem and i have pointed it in my answer.  Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Note: the link in this answer was dead, so I removed it.

Answer (score -1):

You could follow this tutorial  [Here.](http://www.flinkd.org/installing-google-play-on-the-android-emulator-api-21-lollipop/)

or you can also give it try to  **genymotion emulator**  which has **inbuilt play store**   with option of different apis. [Here.](https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/)

Comment: I am already using genymotion. It works fine but i am testing an app which contains google map. In genymotion i have installed gapps so it shows map but it can't retrieve my location even if location option in my laptop is on and i think the tutorial link you have given is needed earlier when android studio doesn't provide any devices with playstore but now android studio avail this. So, i think no need to follow this long tutorial. I have tried to follow this tutorial yesterday but i failed so i leave it. If you have any better solution then please suggest me. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know you are using location services as genymotion does not provide mock location service. In case of that tutorial you could also refer this discussion i found on Stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291902/android-studio-emulator-does-not-come-with-play-store-for-api-23?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: No need to sorry. Thanks for suggestion. I will try it.