# How to install Google Play Market on tablet - Android emulator?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, google-play

If I add a new emulator image of a phone, I can select an image with Play Store.

[image: phone]

But when I try to add an image for a tablet, no option for Play Market is shown. Also, after installing any API, I can't find Play Market.

[image: tablet]

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Comment: @Yupi, sorry, I still have no a solution and postponed it. Several years ago I downloaded images with Google Services and tried to install them. Or used emulators (Bluestacks, Nox, Genymotion, etc), but they often install old versions of SDK.

Comment: Okay thanks for response.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As explained in this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62680047/9905408

You should create a new emulator, before opening it for the first time follow these 3 easy steps:

1- In the AVD Manger go in the Actions overflow menu of the newly created emulator and click on "show on disk". Open "config.ini" with a text editor.

2- change "PlayStore.enabled=false" to "PlayStore.enabled=true"

3- change "image.sysdir.1 = system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86"

to

"image.sysdir.1 = system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86"

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. The message when starting the emulator is that the process has terminated.

Comment: I guess first of all you need to be sure, you have needed system image (for example you can download it for phone emulator and just copy it path to tablet emulator config). And second point be sure you use correct slashes in the path =) in this comment they are for Windows system.

Comment: you can also edit `tag.display = Google Play` and `tag.id = google_apis_playstore` to make it show up in the Device Manager as a Google Play image. I had to Invalidate Caches and restart Android Studio to make this change take effect

Comment: In my case (for Mac), for step 3, I had to change it to the following:

"image.sysdir.1 = system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86/"

Note the forward slash at the end. Thanks!