# Google Play Store on pre Marshmallow Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

What is the sure way of installing Play Store on pre Marshmallow Android Studio Emulator?

There are plenty of tutorials out here that are a complete waste of time.

At least API Level 24 onwards you can choose with Play Store pre-installed.

George

Answer (score 0):

Installing Play Store on `pre Marshmallow`, You will need to create a new Android Virtual Devices and select a hardware device `configuration` compatible with the `Google Play Store`.

[image]

In above screen shot you can see `playstore column` ticks means that emulator is compatible to playstore.

You can refer official site of developer given link below, It is more useful.

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/04/android-studio-24-preview-4-is-now.html

Can you refer this stack overflow link?

[Android Studio emulator does not come with Play Store for API 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291902/android-studio-emulator-does-not-come-with-play-store-for-api-23/38708607)

Before some days, I had also comes error when i tried to create emulator in pre marshmallow and I have solved this using this link's guidance.

Please try this, It will helps you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19616977)

Comment: @ADM Thanks for guide me. I have edited my answer and next time will take care of it.