# Install Google Play Services at emulator(AVD) with Visual Studio

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play-services, emulation, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying deploy an app with Google Maps API since 2 days ago.. But without results, I know it is the emulator problem, I read a lot about install Google Play Services at emulator, but any solutions don't fix my problem.

Someone can help me?

I'm developing Android App with Xamarin and debuggin with XAP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play Services Missing in Emulator (Android 4.4.2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141043/google-play-services-missing-in-emulator-android-4-4-2)

Comment: There are many examples of how to install `Gapps` on various emulators, start here @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31550628/visual-studio-emulator-for-android-install-gapps-google-play-services Google is your friend...

Comment: I've installed Xamarin Android Player.. I download google play service .apk from http://www.androidapksfree.com/apk/ and It's working but with difficulties..

Comment: Don't use XAP, use the Android SDK emulator, just download the atom images for Google Play services (ensure your processor supports HAX) and you will have a lot less of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set target to **Google API's SDK**, also: did you tried to run it on actual Android device?

Comment: Yes.. I also have problems connecting an Android device with Visual Studio