# Play services on Visual Studio Android Emulator not working

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I have installed the Google Play services packages for my Android emulator by following instructions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31550628/visual-studio-emulator-for-android-install-gapps-google-play-services). I have also added an account to my emulator (for Marshmallow) but I still get an error saying "Unfortunately Google play services has stopped". I checked my log cat and I found the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application
com.google.android.gms.common.app.GmsApplication: 
java.lang.SecurityException: addOnPermissionsChangeListener: Neither user 10055 nor current process has android.permission.OBSERVE_GRANT_REVOKE_PERMISSIONS.
```

When I try to give this permission wiht adb pm it fails that too. How can I fix this.

Comment: This permission is one of the `PackageManager` of the platform framework level, I'm not sure what makes this permission missing, but is that OK if you create new emulator which has google play service already instead of using the default one of VS without google play service?