# GooglePlay Installation for Emulator (Marshmallow/Nougat)

Tags: android, google-play-services, emulation

I have tried so many options/blogs/scripts to install GooglePlay for Emulator (running through Android Studio) but it never works. I have seen so many different errors

1. **Failure** [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
2. **Failure** [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
3. **Failure** No space left on /system

*Comment* - Why is it so hard to install GooglePlay on Emulator, **can someone provide steps or GApps that work with Marshmallow/Noughat**. Or Why doesnt Google provide standard steps to install GApps for Emulators !

Here's the gist of what I have tried :

1. Copy GApps from http://opengapps.org/ [ Platform: x86_64; Android: 6 & 7; Variant: full ]
2. Extract the zipped file to temporary folder and then extract following apks from it to another folder

   - gsfcore-all/nodpi/priv-app/GoogleServicesFramework/GoogleServicesFramework.apk
   - gsflogin-all/nodpi/priv-app/GoogleLoginService/GoogleLoginService.apk
   - gmscore-x86_64/nodpi/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk
   - vending-all/nodpi/priv-app/Phonesky/Phonesky.apk
3. Try pushing these apks through this script

   ```
   IMAGE_NAME=Nexus_5X_API_24 #Nexus_5X_API_23
   emulator @${IMAGE_NAME} -no-boot-anim -writable-system &
   adb wait-for-device
   adb root
   adb shell stop
   adb shell 'mount -o remount,rw /system'
   adb push PrebuiltGmsCore.apk /system/priv-app/
   adb push GoogleServicesFramework.apk /system/priv-app/
   adb push GoogleLoginService.apk /system/priv-app/
   adb push Phonesky.apk /system/priv-app/
   adb shell start
   ```

**Latest Error** :  Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]

**How can I make sure that openGApps will be compatible with Android apart from taking these options into account** :

1. Android Version (Noughat/Api 24/Android 7)
2. Platform (x86_64 )

I would really appreciate any help !!

**Reference -**

1. [Android Studio emulator does not come with Play Store for API 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291902/android-studio-emulator-does-not-come-with-play-store-for-api-23)
2. [How to install Google Play app in Android Studio emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757003/how-to-install-google-play-app-in-android-studio-emulator)
3. [How to download Google Play Services in an Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536595/how-to-download-google-play-services-in-an-android-emulator)

Comment: You didn't even follow all the steps in the posts you referenced...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download Google Play Services in an Android emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536595/how-to-download-google-play-services-in-an-android-emulator)

Comment: Not sure how you reached the conclusion that I didnt follow all the steps mentioned in the post as I have gone through them multiple times with nearly 5-6 different Virtual Devices, latest one Nexus_5_API_23 which is giving 'No space left on device' error

Comment: First off the Nexus 5 does not have an x86 processor, second your not remounting system as Read/write

Comment: @ElefantPhace - This post is in reference to Emulator/VirtualDevice, not the actual Nexus5

Comment: did you find a solution? I also get this annoying "no space left on device" though I changed all .ini files, increased system, data, sdcard partition minimum 1024mb

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1, you have now some options of devices that come with the Play Store app built-in(Nexus 5X and Nexus 5 on image below). The current supported versions are Nougat and O.

[image]