# Android Emulator - Tiktok crashing

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtualdisplay

Am using Android Studio 4.2.1 (most current), and observed this behavior in both devices I tried:
Pixel C (API 30)
13.5 Freeform (API 30)

Followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62436883) to get the Play Store on my android emulators, then downloaded Tiktok, and every time I tried to open it, the app loaded very little and crashed after a couple seconds. I even clicked on a Tiktok video from Google search results, which opened up the app, nothing loaded, then it crashed.

TL;DR: When I try to open the Tiktok app in my Android emulator, the app (not the emulator) crashes.

Anyone know a fix for this (Or should I just report the bug to Google?)?

Comment: Pretty sure TikTok detects the emulated environment and closes itself.