# How Can I Get Google Play to Work on Android Emulator in Android Studio Bumblebee +

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, avd-manager

**This issue has been fixed by Google in the newer AS/Emulator**

**NOTE:** Only some API's is available with Playstore, if the one you chose is not available at the creation time, follow this guide

The AVD GUI does NOT allow the selection of Play Images for some reason anymore!
[image]

Answer (score 48):

Since you cannot select the Play store image anymore you need to edit some files

**NOTE:** This may also work in Visual Studio (not tested - some feedback will be apreciated!)

1. Load the image with SDK manager
   [image: SDK Platforms]
2. Create a device with the correct API and Hardware profile and Finish
   [image: AVD]
3. **Before you start this new AVD** you need to Edit the files as follow
   [image: Show on Disc]
4. Edit config.ini (I use VIM but any editor will work)
   Edit the following lines in the file

```
PlayStore.enabled=true
image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-32\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\
tag.display=Google Play
tag.id=google_apis_playstore
```

Note: if you are on a Mac with Apple chip, set this line differently:

```
image.sysdir.1=system-images/android-32/google_apis_playstore/arm64-v8a
```

5. Start the AV Device and check if the Play Icon is available - Test it By logging in!
   [image: Play Store!]
6. ALL DONE!

Comment: I tested Android 13 with Pixel 7 Pro in 2023 (on M2 Mac), and it still works as described. The only change required is this line `image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-32\google_apis_playstore\x86_64` in `arm` based Macs should be `image.sysdir.1 = system-images/android-33/google_apis_playstore/arm64-v8a`

Comment: Yes Thank you, I (sobbing) don't have a Mac to test.

Comment: @Clint Eastwood, at the time of this article, the option to select Google play images was not available.!

Comment: This solution worked for on MacOS, Android API 34, X64_86, Pixel 6 pro.

Answer (score 16):

In the latest Android Studio (Electric Eel), you need to launch SDK Manager, and under SDK Platforms check the "**Show Package Details**" box.  Then select the Google Play images:

[image]

Comment: still google play didnot show after installing system images

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas Try using **Android Studio Canary**.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like Google Play support is now at the device level, rather than when selecting the OS.  And the first devices in the list don't have it.

Ran into the same confusion - turns out needed to scroll down more.

[image]

Comment: Not all of the Sizes has that, only a few and far in between.  In the old days it used to be there for all Sizes.  Tablets for instance - none have it!

Comment: Yes as always, for a long time it was NOT available, and it is NOT available for all Desities
Do NOT spread mis-information please