# Pairing Android Pixel 6 Emulator with Wear OS Emulator: can't install Wear OS app on Tiramisu emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I've been trying to follow these instructions for getting these 2 emulators paired in Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/get-started/creating#pairing-assistant

and I was able to get to the point where I finally have Google Play services set up properly via these instructions: [How Can I Get Google Play to Work on Android Emulator in Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.x.x.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71815181/how-can-i-get-google-play-to-work-on-android-emulator-in-android-studio-bumblebe)

Now I'm going through the Wear OS emulator pairing assistant and I'm stuck at the point of needing to install the Wear OS app on the Tiramisu emulator because I get the device incompatible error:

[screenshot of error in emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPQKZ.png)

I tried searching around for people with similar errors but I haven't quite gotten anywhere!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any specific requirements to try with a Pixel **6** emulator?

If not, try selecting a device that already contains Play Store, like the Pixel **4**, looking at the "Play Store" column in the dialog below:

[image: select hardware dialog showing play store column]

I had no issues installing the Wear OS app with this device.

Comment: Weird, I just tried that and I'm getting the exact same issue!

Comment: [Screenshot of the Pixel 4 error just for completeness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vave5.png)

Comment: I see you are using API 33, could you try with API 32 and see how it goes?

Comment: Ah, okay, that worked!  Thanks so much!

One thing to note is that I ended up downloading the API 32 Google Play image, but then it ended up downloading without the Google API at first.  This resulted in an error in the pairing process where it said I need to update Google Play services on the emulator.   Trying to update in the emulator via the screen launched in the emulator ended up repeatedly failing.  Once I opened SDK Manager and installed the Google API extension(?), I was able to get it to work.

Anyways, thanks again!